# How can I prevent my REDCap surveys being re-sent months after an initial response?

Tags: redcap

A REDCap project is setup so that a participant can enter data via 1) a consent, and 2) an initial survey, and the study team can modify the participant record via 3) another form on the same record months later.

Problem: When the study team modifies the record on instrument 3, an invitation for the initial survey (instrument 2) is unintentionally re-sent to the participant.

The automatic survey invitation logic conditions for the initial survey (instrument 2) specify:

When the following survey is completed:
Instrument 1
AND
When the following logic becomes true:

```
[Variable_in_Instrument_1]='1'
```

I would not expect this (instrument 2 delivery) to trigger again when the study team modifies instrument 3 months later, as there are no references to instrument 3 in the automatic survey invitation logic for instrument 2.

How can I avoid invitation 2 being re-sent to participants when instrument 3 is modified?